# Notifications on remote change

Tags: ios, background-process

I'm developing an application which holds a list of objects. 
The user should be able to favorite some of these objects, which then gets saved for easy access. Simple enough, right.

However, in addition to that, I want it so that the application notifies the user (using a notification, like when you get a new SMS), whenever one of the favorited objects have had something changed (in my application the objects represent a pub, and a change to the pub is when it has a new event scheduled). The change is done on a remote server, using a webpage.

When my app is active I can just poll the server every few minutes and compare the properties of the object, and if I see a change notify the user.

But how will I do to make this work when my app is NOT in the foreground? I want the user to get a notification even if he/she is not currently running my app.

The app does not have any login-functionality, so I can't send out specific push notifications to specific users. So the only thing the server might have access to is perhaps the device ID. I.e. there is no real way for the server to know which favorites a device ID holds.

Is there some smart way to do this? On Android I can just use polling but as iOS doesn't allow code to run in the background in the same way I don't really know how to do.

All help greatly appreciated. Even if it's just a "I don't think that's possible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a table that associates device ID with favorites. When a favorite changes, send that device ID a push notification

The user is the device ID

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not responsible for the server but what you said might work. I should probably have been more clear in my post that what I seek is mostly something that works without having to make changes to the server. 

But this is probably the best (only?) way. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I don't see any other way to do it besides this. I just got done implementing push notifications myself and push sharp really helped me https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp (its a C# project to send the notifications). If that doesn't suit you there is also a python helper